# Power BI Create Running Total using two columns

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix with dates as rows and data in column values. I am trying to create a running total using values from 2 columns. The only issue is that one of the values is updated on a  prior day basis. In other words, both values aren't on the same date. I want to sum the value for TODAY + Value from yesterday.

See example below. I hope it makes sense.

| DATES | COL A | COL B | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/27 |  | 5 |  |
| 3/28 | 10 |  | 15 |
| 3/29 | 10 |  | 25 |
| 3/30 | 3 |  | 28 |

Comment: That answer looks right to me, but if it doesn't meet your use case, maybe show a slightly more real world/concrete example (are you ever going to have data in both columns, etc.)?

Comment: Updated answer with my way of doing this, which is in the dataset itself. But the logic remains the same if you do it in DAX or wherever else really.

Answer (score 0):

Simply join [COL A + DATE] on [COL B + DATE-1Day].

Below is an example on how you can do it in SQL, before it gets into Power BI. If you want it in another manner, please specify language. Personally, I try to do most of my calculations in the dataset itself so the dashboard itself is not that heavy. After this, you simply either set up DAX or an SQL over partition to see the Running Total.

MS SQL Server 2017
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8efed/6

```
CREATE TABLE testjoin
([date] datetime, [col a] int, [col b] int);

INSERT INTO testjoin
    ([date], [col a], [col b])
VALUES
  ('2020-01-01', 1, 1),
  ('2020-01-02', 1, 0),
  ('2020-01-03', 2, 2),
  ('2020-01-04', 3, 1);

select 
a.date, 
case when a.[col a] is null then 0 else a.[col a] end as 'Col A', 
case when b.[col b] is null then 0 else b.[col b] end as 'Col B', 
case when a.[col a] is null then 0 else a.[col a] end + case when b.[col b] is null then 0 else b.[col b] end as 'Total'
from testjoin a
left join testjoin b
on DATEADD(day, -1, a.date)=b.date
```

Result(Do note that th Col B is from the previous date):

| Date | Col A | Col B(From previous date) | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-03 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-01-04 | 3 | 2 | 5 |

Comment: thank you for this. But is there a way to accomplish the same within POWER BI? without using SQL?

Comment: Yes, simply join with DAX. Like stated, the logic remains the same whichever tool you're using.

Comment: What kind of source do you have for this data? As explained, I do not recommend using DAX for this. Might be a personal preference however.